# how can i uninstall a program in elementary os?(newbie)

Tags: applications

Firstly, i should say I'm an elementary os newbie.So I'm really sorry if my question is too basic, pretty please please be patient with me, I'd really appreciate your help.
I installed Elementary OS Freya 2 weeks ago, my first Linux based operating system. I had the usual pictures icon down on my desktop, but i was "smart" enough to try to install a program called "gnome wallpaper slideshow". I got a warning that it gets into conflict with an already existing program or something like that (i think with the embedded photo viewer) but i ignored that warning and installed the program anyway. Now, when I try to open a .jpg (right click-open with...) i only get the option "create background slideshow, and when i click on it nothing happens. I'd like to uninstall this program but i can't seem to find it anywhere. I'd really appreciate your help. I would like to be able and see .jpg files just like it should usually work in Elementary OS. Thank you for your help!

Comment: how do you installed?

Comment: help me E: Unable to locate package maxthon-browse

Answer (score 2):

go to the aplications menu (at the left of the top of your screen) and look for software center, from there you can install and uninstall a lot of things with just a click

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`sudo apt remove *package-name*`

You have to replace package-name with the name of the software you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple uninstall

```
$~sudo apt-get remove 'application_name'
```

Or you can use

```
$~sudo apt-get purge 'application_name'
```

to uninstall the application and all relative files.

It seems in your case like you changed the default application that reads .jpg files.
Go to > System Settings > Applications > Image Viewer 
And choose the default elementaryOS image viewer `Photo Viewer`.

Comment: purge is better for me, since it can clean everythings